# Python exec not accessing variable, exec alternatives

Tags: python, exec, eval

I am writing a command line calculator. I have all the math down but I want to add my own functions, like solve("x^3 = 8", x). My math works fine but the way I'm using exec() is preventing it from writing the result to the local variable finalAnswer.

I included foo() to show what I want

```
def foo():
    return 5
exec("a = foo()")
print(a)

result = "addAB(15,8)"

def addAB(A, B):
    print(A+B)
    return A+B

def __runFunc(fn, param):
    exec("finalAnswer = fn(" + param + ")")

__approvedFunctions = set(["addAB", "subtractAB"])

funcName = result[:result.index('(')]
if(funcName in __approvedFunctions):
    param = result[result.index('(')+1 : result.index(')')]
    if callable(globals()[funcName]):
        __runFunc(globals()[funcName], param)
print(finalAnswer)
```

On execution my output is:

```
addAB(15,8)
5
23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mikeo/OneDrive/Documents/function filter.py", line 45, in 
<module>
    print(finalAnswer)
NameError: name 'finalAnswer' is not defined
```

The first three lines of the output tell me that every part of the script executes, but finalAnswer isn't getting initialized. Have I missed some nuance of using exec().

Also, bonus points if you help me remove exec without changing the format of the string input calling a parameterized function and storing the returned value locally.

Comment: Seems like what you actually want is to evaluate your expressions with [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) and assign the result to a variable, but it's not generally considered a good idea to write code like this.

Comment: Oh goodie. I like bonus points. ;)

Comment: @khelwood It appears that Mikeologist understands that [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), which is why he only attempts to execute approved functions. OTOH, a sufficiently determined attacker could still execute malicious code unless the `param` string is also analyzed for nasties.

Comment: I understand that I should not use exec() but I need to be able to define an extensible function interface. Unless I am misunderstand it eval() wouldn't work with an algorithm like the one in a function such as solve("x^3 + 4 = 12", x). But I'm here asking and removing exec() is a bonus stipulation of my question, so if there's a better way I'd encourage you to post it as an answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need `exec` or `eval` here. If your expressions are all simple, like in your example code, then we can get away with using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which (as the name suggests) can evaluate strings that contain valid Python literals. This makes it far safer than plain `eval` or `exec`. Of course, your code only attempts to execute approved functions, so it *should* be safe, but still...

Anyway, here's a solution. We store the approved functions in a dict, keyed by the function name. And we pretend that the string containing the function argument list is a tuple, and get `literal_eval` to build that tuple for us, so we can pass the args to the function using `*` sequence unpacking.

```
from ast import literal_eval

def addAB(A, B):
    print(A+B)
    return A+B

def subAB(A, B):
    print(A-B)
    return A-B

funcs = (addAB, subAB)
approved_functions = {func.__name__: func for func in funcs}

result = "addAB(15,8)"
i = result.index('(')
func_name, func_args = result[:i], literal_eval(result[i:])
print(func_name, func_args)

if func_name in approved_functions:
    func = approved_functions[func_name]
    final_answer = func(*func_args)
    print(final_answer)
```

**output**

```
addAB (15, 8)
23
23
```

---

This is safe because `ast.literal_eval` is *very* strict about what it'll accept in a string. From the docs:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
>   consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`.

A container display is a list, tuple, set, or dict literal, eg `(2,3,4)` or `{'one':1, 'two': 2}`. If you try to pass `ast.literal_eval` something containing a function call or even an arithmetic expression, eg

```
"(15, f(8))"
```

or

```
"(15, 2 * 4)"
```

it will raise `ValueError: malformed node or string`

There's a minor exception to this. `ast.literal_eval` *will* accept arithmetic expressions that only use `+` or `-`. That's because it needs to be able to evaluate complex number literals, and those literals contain `+` or `-`. The implementers decided that the easy way to handle that is to simply allow `.literal_eval` to evaluate arithmetic expressions containing `+` or `-`; doing so doesn't create a security risk. That only applies to arithmetic expressions though, you cannot do string concatenation with `+`, so

```
a = ast.literal_eval("'ab' + 'cd'")
```

will raise `ValueError`; OTOH, it *does* accept the usual automatic concatenation of adjacent string literals, so this is ok:

```
a = ast.literal_eval("'ab' 'cd'")
```

Comment: That is a much cleaner and safer method of achieving the same goal. Does the prevent malicious use of func_args? I ask because you pointed to this as the potential security flaw in my original code.

Comment: Yes, it's safe because `ast.literal_eval` is very strict about what it'll accept. I'll add that info to my answer...

Comment: Excellent. In my research before asking this question I was unable to find an alternative to eval() for executing functions with parameters. This should help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
    return 5
exec("a = foo()")
print(a)

result = "addAB(15,8)"

def addAB(A, B):
    print(A+B)
    return A+B

def __runFunc(fn, param):

    exec("globals()['finalAnswer']= fn(" + param + ")")

__approvedFunctions = set(["addAB", "subtractAB"])

funcName = result[:result.index('(')]
if(funcName in __approvedFunctions):
    param = result[result.index('(')+1 : result.index(')')]
    if callable(globals()[funcName]):
        __runFunc(globals()[funcName], param)
print(finalAnswer)
```

Comment: I see, so it was working and I was pointing to finalAnswer but because my second exec() call is nested that reference dropped away with that reference frame?